# Protobufer from c++ to c# over Socket

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to send a structer with protocol buffers from c++ to c#. I'm getting an error. Let me explain you the procedure I followed.

**C++ Side**

1- I compiled my .proto file with 2.6.1 protoc

```
message SensorsReport {
required double speed = 1;
required double rpm = 2;}
```

2 - I got my headers, which are a .h file and .cc file. I added to my project and I start to fill my structure.

```
SensorsReport report;                                      // My message with 2 double
report.set_rpm(info.mEngineRPM);                           // I fill the first one
report.set_speed(speedcalculated);                         // I fill the second one
string buf;                                                // Create a string to put the data in
report.SerializeToString(&buf);                            // Serialize data
send(tcp_socket, buf.data(), (int)strlen(buf.data()), 0);  // Send sentece
```

**C# Side**

1- I added to my project protobuf-net dll and I create my class with the message .

```
using System;
using ProtoBuf;


[ProtoContract]
public class SensorsReport
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    double speed { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    double rpm { get; set; }
}
```

2- I create a NetworkStream to get the stream and deserialize.

```
NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
SensorsReport newdata = Serializer.Deserialize<SensorsReport>(stream);
```

This is all my procedure and I'm getting the next error : Invalid wire-type
I have read that is something releated with the way to create the messages but I think I have everything right. Haven't I?

Comment: No, if something doesn't work, everything is not right !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. Was not to fix the length of the received buffer. You have to set yor buffer same as the send message. For example if your message is 32 bytes length, your buffer will be :

```
byte[] data = new byte[32];
recv = newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
```

The problem now is i do not know how length is going to be my message...anyway i found out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` should not be used for determining the length of a buffer

```
send(tcp_socket, buf.data(), (int)strlen(buf.data()), 0);
```

in the case of binary data. `buf.length()` might work better.

Comment: Does `IsRequired=true` in `[ProtoMember(1, IsRequired=true)]` and `[ProtoMember(2, IsRequired=true)]` make any difference?

Comment: I tried to do it with files and it works perfect. Is something releated with the sockets... I'll post the solution if i find out the problem.